# Cost of hosting an OSM tile server with similar performance to Google Maps API

Tags: openstreetmap, tiles, google-maps-api, tile-server

I am considering switching from Google Maps API to hosting my own OSM tile server.

Right now my site gets about 2,000 map hits a day, serving about 20-30 users at a time.  With Google Maps API, I would have to pay about $250 a month, and the cost could skyrocket if I grow fast.

If I were to host my own tile server, and to match the loading speed/performance of Google Maps API, how many CPU's and GB's of RAM would I need?  I will be most likely be using a [Droplet on DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing/) to host it.

Apologies beforehand for the relatively broad question.

Comment: How big an area do you want the map to cover?  What level of detail do you want to show?

Comment: @SomeoneElse I just need to cover all of Ontario, Canada to start off.  The level of detail should be as close to Google Maps API as possible.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to match Google speed/performance but with a smaller number of simultaneous users? Since you're doing this already, could you use your existing server stats to estimate what you'll need?

Comment: @barrycarter My existing server stats are used for hosting my web app, but not for hosting a tile server.  I have no idea how much CPU/RAM a tile server would require to run as smoothly as Google Maps API.  My question is the estimated cost for hosting a tile server that can serve up to 50 users simultaneously with great performance.

Comment: I'm thinking you could use digitalocean's free trial, unless that's not an option for you. You could also use Amazon's free server tier to get an idea. Or is the problem that you don't have a 50-user load to test with?

Comment: Your question seems overly broad to be answered in a meaningful way. I don't know why you want to set up a tile server in the first place. Google uses vector maps, while a tile server would be used to serve rendered png images. Those are totally different technologies you're trying to compare to each other. I'd suggest to evaluate vector tiles in more detail, e.g. https://openmaptiles.org - What about update intervals?